# Replace default page in IIS with app summary

Tags: iis

Is there a built in feature in IIS so that the default page (the root one) shows a list of all configured web pages?

Comment: If you cannot describe clearly what you wanted, this is very likely something IIS doesn't support.

Comment: I want that the browser shows a list of all web sites configured on this iis instance.
Same result as PowerShell-Command "Get-IISSite"

Comment: No such a thing. You need to write such a page yourself.

Comment: The default page you are talking about is the default page of iis, or the default page you requested? If it is the requested default page, it can be modified through Default Document.